# Cohomology of $G/T$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-groups

I discovered a very beautiful proof [here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/notes5.pdf) that if $G$ is a compact connected Lie group and $T$ a maximal torus then any element $x \in G$ is conjugated to an element of $T$. But for conclude one needs to know the cohomology of $G/T$ (more precisely one needs to know that $G/T$ has a CW-decomposition with only even cells). Apparently this can be done using Morse theory. But I couldn't find anything about this topic in the notes.

I would be very interested to know more about it, where could I find such proof ?

Comment: I'm largely ignorant about the Lie group side of the theory, but my first thought would be to try the [Bruhat decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_decomposition).

Comment: Oh this looks exactly what I needed, and in addition we get that $\chi(G/T) = |W(G)|$ as stated. Thanks !